# .NET Core 2.2 UserManager.CreateAsync not allowed for duplicate usernames

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add a duplicate username but from another tenant to my user database. However, my `createasync` always `returns` an error saying that a duplicate username was found.

I have already removed the index from my normalizedusername column but the error still occurs.

I have found this code that is supposed to overwrite the `usermanager`

```
protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry,IDictionary<object, object> items)
{
    if (entityEntry != null && entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        var errors = new List<DbValidationError>();
        var user = entityEntry.Entity as TUser;
        //check for uniqueness of user name and email
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (Users.Any(u => String.Equals(u.UserName, user.UserName)))
            {
                errors.Add(new DbValidationError("User",
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, IdentityResources.DuplicateUserName, user.UserName)));
            }
            if (RequireUniqueEmail && Users.Any(u => String.Equals(u.Email, user.Email)))
            {
                errors.Add(new DbValidationError("User",
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, IdentityResources.DuplicateEmail, user.Email)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var role = entityEntry.Entity as TRole;
            //check for uniqueness of role name
            if (role != null && Roles.Any(r => String.Equals(r.Name, role.Name)))
            {
                errors.Add(new DbValidationError("Role",
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, IdentityResources.RoleAlreadyExists, role.Name)));
            }
        }
        if (errors.Any())
        {
            return new DbEntityValidationResult(entityEntry, errors);
        }
    }
    return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
}
```

I have placed this within my `ApplicationDbContext`. However its saying that it cannot find `DbEntityValidationResult` and they cannot find a suitable method to overwrite.

Am I missing something else? How can I implement this code?

EDIT: The method provided above does not work with `.net Core 2.2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow user to register with duplicate UserName using Identity Framework 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094063/how-to-allow-user-to-register-with-duplicate-username-using-identity-framework-1)

Comment: Hello, kinda yes and kinda no, where do I implement those classes? In the applicationdbcontext?

Comment: Also, with the validate method? I did place it below the onmodelcreating but it shows the above errors. I’m using .net core 2.2 if it makes it easier

Comment: Just re-read the link provided, that method is outdated.

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism to support multi-tenancy in ASP.NET Core. If you want that, you either have to use some existing library for that, or you will have to build a lot of stuff yourself. Detailing all that is really out of the scope of a Stack Overflow answer though. – If you want to go the route yourself, then check out how Identity’s `UserManager` and `UserStore` work and see what you will need to do to replace those by a multi-tenant aware alternative.

Comment: Is there a way to override UserManagers Createasync?

Comment: You can override the ApplicationUser class