# How to allow duplicate user in .net core identity

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

.Net core identity allows us to set false to unique email but we want to allow duplicate username

[image]

because a username can be applied to multiple district id in our application.

Our clients don't want to concatenation like (username + district id)

So let me know if there is any proven solution for it . Thanks in advance

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. How would the system know which account is logging in? Why not just give access to appropriate things to the one account?

Comment: Look this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094063/how-to-allow-user-to-register-with-duplicate-username-using-identity-framework-1

Comment: that is 7 years old , and i'm not able to implement that to current .net version

Comment: @VasanthR you would have to extend the identity provider, it won't support that "out of the box", so the answer may be old but the premise is still sound. If using a 3rd party is an option I would think a service like Auth0 (no affiliation) could support your needs.

Comment: The answer is only 5 years old, but the approach it outlines is the solution to your problem. Find or add a column on your users table that is not constrained to be unique (email, or add a one-to-many table to allow a user to have multiple emails, or add something else). Then add custom logic to check these identifiers during the login method.